# PDFTron PDF to XOD conversion throws exception System.AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, pdftron, pdfnet

The below code that converts a PDF document to XOD using PDFNet [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PDFNet/6.8.56.6513) package (v6.8.56.6513) throws an exception. However, the previous [version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PDFNet/6.8.2.65223) (v6.8.2.65223) of the nuget package works without any problem. To produce the issue, please download [this file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By-MaraBtHPdMHRqTXhlVGlYc28/view?usp=sharing).

Platform: .Net Framework v4.7.2, x64.

```
using System;
using pdftron;

namespace PdfTronTest2
{
    class Program
    {
        private static PDFNetLoader loader = PDFNetLoader.Instance();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                PDFNet.Initialize();
                pdftron.PDF.Convert.ToXod("art of unit testing.pdf", "art of unit testing.xod");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
System.AccessViolationException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
   at trn.PDF.Convert.ToSilverlight(UString* , UString* , Obj* , Boolean )
   at pdftron.PDF.Convert.ToXod(String in_filename, String out_filename)
   at PdfTronTest2.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\mvinchhi\source\repos\PdfTronTest2\PdfTronTest2\Program.cs:line 15
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed report. I have reproduced the issue and am investigating. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you again for the detailed report.

The issue has been fixed, and our production channel has been patched. You will be able to download a patched production build starting tomorrow, from our nightly build site.

I see you posted to our forum, so I will provide you more details there on when and where to get the download.